# BasicQos and Round Robin

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I want to distribute tasks among several servers in a round-robin fashion, and each server should handle at most number of CPU core tasks at a time.

In Java the number of tasks to prefetch can be controlled like this:

```
int prefetchCount = 4; // would be number of cores in actual app
channel.basicQos(prefetchCount);
```

But now assume I have two servers A and B, each having the same setting to prefetch 4 tasks. And lets say I put 5 tasks on the queue. Does this then mean that server A will consume 4 tasks from the queue, and server B 1? Or are the tasks still distributed round-robin?

Answer (score 0):

the tasks will be delivered round-robin based on availability of the worker.

it's possible that one server could say "i can take 4 messages" and it would receive 4, leaving only 1 available for the other server.

however, there's no guarantee it would happen this way, and no guarantee that the messages would be round-robin delivered, one message at a time to each server.

the criteria for delivery includes message arrival, message and consumer priority, consumer availability, and other factors.

this page has some good info on the subject https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-priority.html